# Kli Yakar on vegetarianism and the purpose of kashrut

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, kashrut-kosher

[This article](https://www.jewishveg.org/schwartz/kook-expanded.html) cites [Kli Yakar to Deuteronomy 12:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Kli_Yakar_on_Deuteronomy.12.20.1?lang=bi) as saying - and this is presented as a direct translation of the Kli Yakar:

> What was the necessity for the entire procedure of ritual slaughter?
> For the sake of self-discipline. It is far more appropriate for man
> not to eat meat. Only if he has a strong desire for meat does the
> Torah permit it, and even this only after the trouble and
> inconvenience necessary to satisfy his desire. Perhaps because of the
> bother and annoyance of the whole procedure, he will be restrained
> from such a strong and uncontrollable desire for meat.

But I can't see any such content in the Kli Yakar's commentary. Can anyone help (eg does this passage appear in Kli Yakar to a different verse maybe? Or am I missing something obvious?)

Comment: To be totally accurate, the article presents this as a quote from Kli Yakar cited in Chill's *The Commandments and Their Rationale*, without giving a reference to anywhere in Kli Yakar. Commentary to Deuteronomy 12:20 is the cite in the second source (*The Vision of Eden*) mentioned in that footnote.

Comment: @JoelK is right, it does appear on first glance to be a direct quote, but actually it isn't clear that it is. Therefore consider closing the question or modifying in such a way that answers can be made on the idea rather than the direct quote

Comment: @RabbiKaii The article introduces "words of the illustrious Torah commentator … K'li Yakar", followed by a colon, followed by an indented quote. I think that's clear enough for me to pose the question.

Comment: הנני מתיר לך הדבר 'וזבחת מבקרך' וגו' כאשר ציוויתיך – לא בכל עת, כי אם לפרקים, בעת התגברות התאווה. וזהו שנאמר 'אך כאשר יאכל את הצבי ואת האייל כן תאכלנו'. לפי שנאמר 'וכי יצוד אדם ציד – חיה או עוף' ואמרו רז"ל: לימדה תורה דרך ארץ, שלא יאכל אדם בשר כי אם בהזמנה הזאת, ביאור הדבר הוא שאם ירגיל האדם את עצמו לאכול מן הבהמות המצויין אתו בבית, שור או כשב או עז, כל היום יתאווה, וירגיל עצמו באכילתו דבר יום ביומו. אבל אם לא יאכל עד אשר יצוד ביערות ובמדברות ציד חיה או עוף שיש לו סכנה וטורח גדול לצודם, אז תשקיט תאוותו, כי אין האכילה שווה בגודל הצער והטורח... ומחמת הטורח הוא ממעט באכילתן, כך יאכל אפילו סתם בשר

Comment: Continue reading... it's there

Comment: @deuteronomy That doesn’t include the wording attributed (“what was the necessity for the entire procedure”, “bother and annoyance”, “he will be restrained”…)

Comment: @Zarka its a literary translation. "what was the necessity for the entire procedure" = "הנני מתיר לך הדבר" , "bother and annoyance" = "טורח גדול" , "he will be restrained" = "תשקיט תאוותו...ממעט באכילתן" .... I don't think its the best translation either, but to me it seems clear that this is the section he is quoting.